# Hyperledger Composer: Is a customer a participant or an asset?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have pet-stores, customers, and cats.

Pet-stores sell cats to customers through a website.
Customers can have 0 or more cats.

Every time a pet-store sells a cat to a customer, the pet-store logs the transaction in the blockchain.

So the model is:
Pet-store = Participant
Cat = Asset

What would the customer be? Asset or Participant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A customer would be a participant in this business network. If you're confused about the difference between asset and participant, then remember that an asset is something that can change ownership. Like in your example the cat is changing owners from cat-store to customers.